# Setting has_many through collections by changing foreign key values on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Patient` that `has_many` `Phenotype`s through `PatientsPhenotype`s.

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :patients_phenotypes
    has_many :phenotypes, through: :patients_phenotypes
end

class PatientsPhenotype < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :phenotype
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :properties # Information associated with each row in this join table
end

class Phenotype < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :patients_phenotypes
    has_many :patients, through: :patients_phenotypes
end
```

Because some patient records are out of date, I want to re-associate the phenotypes belonging to old patient records to new patient records. I can't simply add the phenotypes directly to the patients using `patient.phenotypes << phenotype`, because the associations carry other information that is tied to the join table record itself, such as `user_id` and `properties`.

What I've tried to do to accomplish this is setting a join table instance's FK from the old patient to the new patient, then adding this join table instance to the new patient's join table collection.

```
patient_phenotype.patient_id
# => (old_patient_id)
patient_phenotype.patient_id = new_patient.id
patient_phenotype.save
new_patient.patients_phenotypes << patient_phenotype
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
new_patient.phenotypes
# => []
```

What's going wrong here? Would I be better off simply creating an entirely new `PatientsPhenotype` and re-assigning it the information belonging to the original `PatientsPhenotype`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you run `new_patient.phenotypes` execute `new_patient.reload`.

Comment: Beautiful! I wish I knew that was necessary. I notice, though, that I had to fire `reload` after I saved any changes I made to the model.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `inverse_of` in your models.